# TypeScript: function alias in .d.ts

Tags: typescript

U function in a Node module I'm trying to describe in `.d.ts` has two aliases, `config()` and `load()` ([see the source](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js#L82)). The function can be described like this in `dotenv/index.d.ts`:

```
export function config(options?: dotenvOptions): Object;
```

How do I also export it under the other alias, `load()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a type:

```
declare type ConstructorMethod = (options?: dotenvOptions) => Object;
```

(name can be better)

Then export the two methods as the same type:

```
export const config: ConstructorMethod;
export const load: ConstructorMethod;
```

P.S. Looks like the return type is actually `object | boolean`. Union types might be annoying, but I thought I might point you in this direction in case you become annoyed in future: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html (the section on type guards and differentiating types). Just something cool I only recently came across.

Comment: Thanks. I actually think the type is `Object | false`. I've submitted a PR to DefinitelyTyped with the fix.